# Can't find closest element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When I click on the button it should find a dropdown and then it should get the text of the selected option from the dropdown, but it can't find the input field with the class `Tasktitle`. Updating title afterwards it should get the text from the dropdown.
Can anyone please help me?

**HTML**

```html
<div class="card">
    <a href="#" onclick="OpenCloseSections(this); return false;" class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="card-header">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="Tasktitle" value="On hold" />  <-- Find & update this element
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="panel-body Panel">
        <div id="cdbodytwo" class="card-body">
            <div class="panel-body PanelChild">

                <div id="cdbodytwo" class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="button" onclick="UpdateOpgaveStatus(this);" >Update status</button>
                                <select class="opgavestatus">
                                    <option value="">I gang</option>
                                    <option value="1">Venter på vare</option>
                                    <option value="2">Venter på svar</option>
                                    <option value="3">På hold</option>
                                    <option value="4">I gang</option>
                                    <option value="5">Færdig</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function UpdateOpgaveStatus(element) {

    var GetStatusText = $(element).closest('div').find('.opgavestatus option:selected').text();
    var FindTitle = $(element).closest('div').find('.Tasktitle');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/User/UpdateOpgaveStatus",
        data: {},

        success: function (result) {
            FindTitle.html(GetStatusText); 
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `$(this).closest('div')` gets the parent div, which does not contain `.TaskTitle` element. You need to get the `.card` element instead and `find()` within that:

```
var FindTitle = $(element).closest('.card').find('.Tasktitle');
```

In addition this is an `input` element so you need to use `val()` to update it, not `html()`:

```
FindTitle.val(GetStatusText);
```

It's also worth noting that block level elements, such as `div` should not be placed inside inline elements, such as `a`. In addition inline event handlers are no longer good practice and should be avoided. As you've already loaded jQuery in to the page you can use that instead to attach your event handlers unobtrusively, something like this:

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <input type="text" name="name" class="Tasktitle" value="On hold" />
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body Panel">
    <div id="cdbodytwo" class="card-body">
      <div class="panel-body PanelChild">
        <div id="cdbodytwo" class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button">Update status</button>
                <select class="opgavestatus">
                  <option value="">I gang</option>
                  <option value="1">Venter på vare</option>
                  <option value="2">Venter på svar</option>
                  <option value="3">På hold</option>
                  <option value="4">I gang</option>
                  <option value="5">Færdig</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.card-header').on('click', function() {
    OpenCloseSections(this);
  });

  $('.card-body button').on('click', function() {
    let $button = $(this);
    var statusText = $button.closest('div').find('.opgavestatus option:selected').text();
    var title = $button.closest('.card').find('.Tasktitle');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/User/UpdateOpgaveStatus",
      success: function(result) {
        title.html(statusText);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Error");
      }
    });
  });
});
```